# where is chat history of Skype for Business is stored in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, skype-for-business

For Skype application, the chat logs are stored into the main.db file of skype user folder.
Now I want to backup my chat logs from Skype for business application. I am trying to find out the chat logs file like main.db but it does not exist for business application.
Where is the Skype for Business stores users chat log in Windows 7?

Answer (score -1):

Either in the cloud or in your main.db - it depends on your own settings. If you can't see them in main.db you may need to change your settings. More here: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA392/where-can-i-find-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-windows-desktop-and-what-can-i-do-with-it

Comment: I don't want chat history from simple Skype application. 
I want chat history from "Skype for Business" application.

Comment: In your Outlook folders you should see 'Conversation History', from there you can archive them.

Comment: can you please give me the path of 'Conversation History' folder? How to programmatically capture the chat logs from "Skype for Business"  application?

Comment: I don't think it's a local folder with a path, it's a virtual folder which pulls Skype for business messages from your Exchange server and probably stores them in your OST. If you access the conversation history folder via outlook and right click - properties - autoarchive it is possible to auto archive these messages locally with whatever frequency you like without the need to programmatically do anything yourself.

Comment: OK. Is there any SDK  to retrieve the chat logs from "Skype for Business" application?